# Unlocking from kids mode back to factory settings

Tags: factory-reset

My grandkids installed and lock kids mode on my galaxy tab4. I however don't know the password.  How can I unlock this back to factory setting??

Answer (score 0):

this link should help you under the : "Master reset using the hardware keys" part.
However be sure to backup all the data you want to keep **before** resetting.

[Master Reset Steps](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-11553)